# Filling an order form in google sheets via telegram-bot and google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram-bot

I am trying to fill an order form in google sheets via telegram-bot. 
After user typed name of order form (eg. "Sheet1") I want to send user items from order form one item at a time and fill relevant answers to google sheet.

eg: 
User: Sheet1. Bot: Apple. User: 5. Bot: Banana. User: 2

[example of an order form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldkuo.jpg)

For now I can send to user all items in one answer, but I cann't figure out how to send one item at time and write answer to a corresponding cell.

```
var token = "xxx"; //token of telegram-bot from BotFather
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxx/exec"; 
var ssId = "xxx"; /*token of google spreadsheet in
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/edit#gid=0 */

function getMe() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/getMe";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);}

function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);}

function sendText(id,text) {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + text;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hi there");}

function doPost(e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = data.message.text;
  var id = data.message.chat.id;
  var name = data.message.chat.first_name;

  var out = [];  //array to store name of all sheets in spreadsheet
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets(); 
  for (var y = 0 ; y < sheets.length ; y++) { 
  out.push( [ sheets[y].getName() ] );}

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(text);

  if (inArray(text, out) == true){
    var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
      if (cache.get('order') == text){
        var range_test = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(text).getRange("A1:A3").getValues();
        //B10 value is 0
        var range_item = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(text).getRange("B10").getValues();


        for (var r = 0; r < range_test.length; r++){       
          //send to telegram names of all items
          sendText(id,range_test[r])}


        //trying to cash some values and write it to a cell 
        var cashed_item = cache.put(range_item, range_test[0], 30);
        var cashed_item_get = cache.get(range_item)
        sheet.getRange('A9').setValue(text);
        sheet.getRange('A10').setValue(cashed_item_get);

        } 
      else {
            // Puts the value from text into the cache using the key 'order' 
            var cached = cache.put('order', text, 30)}
     } 
   else {sendText(id,"Error. Write the correct vendor name")
          sendText(id,out)}
}

function inArray(target, array) {
  for(var k = 0; k < array.length; k++)  {
    if(array[k] == target) {
      return true; }
     }
      return false; 
     }
```

For now code above works like this: [PrtScn from telegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdPFu.jpg). User enters name of vendor two times and gets answer with names of all items.

Comment: You need to troubleshoot your code.  [Link to troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Comment: Read [mcve] and [ask] to improve chances of getting a answer.

Comment: @SandyGood code is working. But I don't know how to solve problem of sending items, getting answer from user and store it to a corresponding cell.

Comment: Your code may not be creating any errors, but you need to know exactly what it is doing.  And we don't know what it's doing.  For example, your code is getting values from "A1:A3" but your image shows a range that is different, and I don't see any range in the code that matches your image.  One issue for anyone trying to help is the difference between help and work.  We would need to do work, that you should be doing in order to give you the answer.  You need to narrow down the section of code that is critical.  It's good to show all the code, but narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("666").getRange(57, 1).setValue([text])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).